# Change screen colour depending on time of day

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, screen

I always go on my machine when it is light, lose track of time, and when I look outside again, it is dark. So I was wondering if there was some sort of app which would change the colour of your screen in a very gradual way to show you the day going by? Just so that the screen's shade slightly changes. I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18. Also I would prefer this to be something that I can install from the repositories so that I can definitely trust it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Redshift` is the app just for you then! **Install** it with:

```
sudo apt-get install redshift-gtk
```

And then run it with the same package name.

Though you will have to turn location services on by going `System Settings > Privacy` and then turning them on if they are not already on (this should be roughly in the same place on other flavours):

[image]

**Description:**

```
Adjusts the color temperature of your screen with GTK+ integration
The color temperature is set according to the position of the sun. A
different color temperature is set during night and daytime. During
twilight and early morning, the color temperature transitions smoothly
from night to daytime temperature to allow your eyes to slowly
adapt.
```

To configure it to autostart just launch it and then turn on `Autostart` in its appindicator menu:

[image]

I am sorry that I cannot provide screenshots for comparison as the shading does not affect the screenshots, which is probably for the best.

Comment: What about [f.lux](http://justgetflux.com)?

Comment: @Zacharee1: As I said in the question I would prefer something in one of the main repositories for security reasons.

Comment: Took ya long enough ;). OK.

Comment: Would it be in poor taste to also make an answer recommending f.lux?